# Reject в Promise вызывает ошибку, хотя код правильный?

Tags: node.js

Почему при выполнении данного кода возникает ошибка:

```
[UnhandledPromiseRejection: This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). The promise rejected with the reason "#<Object
>".] {
  code: 'ERR_UNHANDLED_REJECTION'
}
```

Код:

```js
const axios = require('axios');

(async () => {
    const get_login_and_password = () => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            let res = {
                success: false
            }

            axios
                .get('http://test.site/index.php', {
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    }
                })
                .then((response) => {
                    if (response.data?.email && response.data?.password) {
                        res.success = true
                        res.email = response.data.email
                        res.password = response.data.password
                    } else {
                        res.message = 'Nothing data: EMail and password!'
                    }
                })
                .catch((e) => {
                    res.message = e.message
                })
                .finally(() => {
                    if (res.success) {
                        resolve(res)
                    } else {
                        reject(res)
                    }
                })
        })
    }

    console.log(await get_login_and_password())
})()
```

Всем спасибо!

Comment: Ну потому что вы вызвали `reject(res)` видимо

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Подскажите пожалуйста, как этот код должен выглядеть в правильном исполнении?

Comment: А что конкретно вы хотите получить-то?

Comment: В случае если res.success = false отбросить reject, а если = true тогда resolve()

Comment: Ну так именно это в коде и написано, и всё работает как надо. В чём проблема-то?

Comment: Я же описал какая ошибка в консоли появляется: ERR_UNHANDLED_REJECTION

Comment: Всё правильно, вы же не обработали reject'нутый промис, о чём система заботливо вас предупредила. Если вы хотите, чтобы не предупреждала, — обработайте его любым удобным для вас способом

Comment: Собственно, в тексте ошибки даже сразу написано, какими способами её можно обработать

Comment: Если не затруднит, можете пожалуйста показать (приложить ответ) как это сделать правильно? Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо просто обработать **reject** с помощью **catch**

```
console.log(await get_login_and_password().catch(e => e))
```

Можно так же обрабатывать **reject** в **then** во втором параметре:

```
console.log(await get_login_and_password().then(
    res => {
        // Обработчик события resolve
    }, 
    rej => {
        // Обработчик события reject
    })
);
```

Если есть необработанный **reject** вы и получаете ошибку **UnhandledPromiseRejection**

Comment: `reject` тоже попадает в `then` - просто во второй параметр

Comment: @Grundy Да, согласен. Я про это уже подзабыл, привык делить успешно от неуспешно **then / catch**